# Help between 2n2222 and 2n2222a?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, ttl

I am thinking about ordering this:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/x100-Fairchild-PN2222A-2N2222A-NPN-Small-Signal-TO-92-Transistors-US-Seller-/171520659038?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27ef6d8e5e

and I have no idea (Google has not proven helpful) what is the big difference between a 2n2222 and 2n2222a Transistor. I am using these for logic gates (for now just basic AND, NOT, and am working on my own full adder). I wish to buy the 100 pack on EBay, as it is cheap compared to buying a 15-pack at RadioShack (which only contains 5 of the kind I use) for a couple of bucks. What should I know, though, about 2n2222a and its use in logic gates (like different collector, emitter, base, etc.)?

Comment: What do the datasheets say?

Comment: Go to Digikey and buy 100 2N3904 for $11. It's another jellybean NPN. It looks like manufacturers are EOLing 2N2222s in non SMT packages, and that is making the remaining stock more expensive. Finally, do not buy electronic components on eBay. Ever. You don't know what you're getting, and more often than not they're fake.

Comment: Yeah, I had my thoughts about EBay. Main thing is, I just need a transistor that is perfectly (at most, just have to change which wire is which on a breadboard or so) compatible with 2N2222. I am looking up the 2N3904 now.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=166246585&uq=635591149259038762&CSRT=7292701523346090918  That the right one? 100 of them is about 11 dollars. They seem just what I need, based on what I have looked up.

Comment: 2N3904BU is a Fairchild number. Really, for what you're doing any old small signal NPN will work.

Comment: Perfectly compatible sounds like an interesting idea :-). If the 2222 worked, the 2222a will work.

Comment: At least in buying the Radio Shack parts you save on postage.  I recall the 15 pack contains a mix of similar NPN parts.  They likely also have a similar pack of PNP parts which would help in some learning and experimenting.  If you happen to check back at Radio Shack they may soon be having a "Going Out of Business" sale.

Comment: You do NOT need parts perfectly the same. You want same spec of better and eve wose spec probably ok 99.8% of time. Best of all if chap (and sometimes are use BC337-40 & BC327-40 (pnp) Often as cheap as any and notably better than many low end jellybean parts.

Comment: I know about that...sucks that RadioShack is going out of business. But I heard that not all stores are closing, some are staying open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both parts are about the same.   The 2n2222A is a slight bit better in terms of Vceo, Vcbo, Vebo.  But if you are not planning on stressing the part (higher voltages, etc) both will work well, especially for simple switching and logic circuits.  The 2n2222 part is the older style part which might be the reason they are being offered at a low price.

Answer (score -1):

[image: some basic parameters of difference and each variants]

do find above some basic parameters of difference and each variants need to ascertained before use as there seems to be a "flood" of wrong one in the market

Comment: The images are identical, aside from the lettering added on; there don't seem to be any "basic parameters" differing here. (Note the question did not ask about **PN**2222s.) Could you be more specific?